# Gluing filtered object from associated graded pieces

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

So, I believe the following result is correct but do not know the exact reference (and not sure to what extent what I'm saying is true). If anyone could give a reference for this it would be great.

1) Consider three objects in some abelian category, $F_1, F_2, F_3$. Then objects with filtrations $F^1 \subset F^2 \subset F^3$ such that $F^1 = F_1, F^2/F^1 = F_2, F^3/F^2 = F_3$ are classified by triples $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ of extension elements, $\alpha \in Ext^1(F_2, F_1), \beta \in Ext^1(F_3, F_2), \gamma \in Ext^1(F_3, F_1)$, such that the Yoneda product $\alpha \beta \in Ext^2(F_3, F_1)$ vanishes.

2) Similar result should hold for any amount of objects at least for the case of linear category in characteristic zero - the ways of gluing objects $F_1, ..., F_n$ into a filtered object $F^1 \subset F^2 \subset ... \subset F^n$ such that $F^k / F^{k-1} = F_k$ should be classified by Maurer-Cartan elements in the algebra $\bigoplus_{j>i}RHom^{\bullet}(F_j, F_i)$ (considered as either dgla or L-infinity algebra).

I also know that this type of questions frequently appear in the theory of mixed hodge structures (but unable to find any direct reference, too).

Edit: added forgotten $\gamma$

Comment: It is not precisely correct. You need to specify how it is zero and this is an extra piece of information. For example you might have a case in which both the first pair and the second are glued trivially but the third object is glued no trivially to the first. In this case all the information lies in the trivialization

Comment: Excuse me, I've definitely forgot that I also need an element in Ext^1(F_3, F_1), but I think in case of three objects this is all data I need: you are talking about some kind of Massey product and for three objects there won't be any.

Comment: One comment is that you can think of the equivalence you are defining as Koszul duality for representations of the $A_n$ quiver.  The Koszul dual (linear) category to the $A_n$ quiver is the category $Ch_n$ whose representations are chain complexes. The structure you get on the associated gradeds  is exactly a homotopy coherent chain complex $Ch_n \to D(A)$  which takes the $k$th object to $F_k [k]$.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov This "more data you need" is precisely there, from my perspective, to indicate the different options for trivializing $\alpha \beta$: every two such trivializations differ by a class in $Ext^1$. Note that it has still some ambiguity in this class of the form $\alpha \xi$ for $\xi:F_3\to F_2$, as in Kuhn's answer.

Comment: Lets choose some resolutions of our objects. Then I think we both agree that the data specified is an element $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \in \bigoplus_{j>i} RHom^{\bullet}(F_j, F_i)$, satisfying Maurer-Cartan condition $\alpha \beta = d \gamma$. The solutions of such equations are in $1-1$ correspondense to solutions of this equation in any quasiisomorphic dg-algebra.

However, in this case this algebra is formal (quasiisomorphic to its cohomology), and the equation reduces to $\alpha \beta = 0$.

This works only for char=0 however.

Comment: However, the answer to this question suggests I'm doing something wrong but I can not quite recognize *what*: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301641/spelling-out-explicitly-the-data-of-a-two-step-filtration-in-terms-of-pieces-and?rq=1

Comment: The argument why this algebra is formal is just that it should be quaiisomorphic to its cohomology with $A_{\infty}$-structure (transferred by Kadeishvili's theorem) and this $A_{\infty}$-structure doesn't have any higher operations (aka Massey products) because of the grading reasons.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov We definitely agree on that, except that I would prefer to say "the equation reduces to $\alpha \beta= 0$ **and** $d\gamma  = 0$. This is essentially the same as choosing a chain killing $\alpha \beta$ in advance (in the non-formal case) and consider $\gamma$ as the difference from our's and the fixed one. And again, it is not unique but rather defined inside the ideal of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ because we can change $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by a coboundary, even in the formal case, and this affects $\gamma$, even in the formal case!

Comment: In formal case we have no d?...

(I believe my argument proves that 2-step extensions with fixed isomorphism to the associated graded module ARE classified by triples $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in$ their respective $Ext$ groups with $\alpha \beta = 0$ and no additional conditions. do we agree on that statement?)

Comment: No, excuse me, $\gamma$ is even defined up to addition of elements of the form $\alpha \psi$ and $\phi \beta$, where $\psi \in Hom(F_3, F_2), \phi \in Hom(F_2, F_1)$. But is still does not leave Ext-groups.

Comment: We agree on everything.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov Leva, hi. One comment: all Maurer-Cartan solutions aren't invariant under quasiisomorphism, only those close to the identity are (meaning a functor on f.d. nilpotent algebras). Consider the case of an acyclic dg-Lie algebra which is one-dimensional in degrees 1 and 2 and zero everywhere else, with the differential an identity map and a multiplication of two numbers for the bracket. It has two Maurer-Cartan solutions.

Comment: @GrishaPapayanov hi! I didn't think about it - but it seems correct for me now, the thing which is invariant is the germ of solutions mod gauge group equivalence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would think about this:  $\alpha \in Ext^1(F_2,F_1)$ corresponds to a short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow F_1 \xrightarrow{i} F(1,2) \xrightarrow{p} F_2 \rightarrow 0.$$ 
Similarly $\beta \in Ext^1(F_3,F_2)$ corresponds to a short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow F_2 \rightarrow F(2,3) \rightarrow F_3 \rightarrow 0.$$ 
The first short exact sequence induces a long exact sequence including
$$ Hom(F_3,F_2) \xrightarrow{\alpha \circ} Ext^1(F_3,F_1) \xrightarrow{i_*}  Ext^1(F_3,F(1,2)) \xrightarrow{p_*} Ext^1(F_3,F_2) \xrightarrow{\alpha \circ} Ext^2(F_3,F_1),$$ 
and from this one sees that an $F(1,2,3) \in Ext^1(F_3,F(1,2))$ exists such that $F(1,2,3)/F_1 = F(2,3)$ if and only if $\alpha \circ \beta = 0 \in Ext^2(F_3,F_1)$.  Furthermore, choices correspond to the image of $i_*$.  Perhaps this is the classification you desire.  I don't know of a reference, but the argument is just using basic triangulated category/homological algebra techniques.

Understanding filtered objects with 4 or more composition factors leads one quickly to Massey products.  Ambiguities tend to get out of hand unless one has something special going on in the case in hand.

Comment: Yes, I have something similar in mind (and for general result it should follow from formal deformation theory). I actually search for a reference though so I won't accept the answer for now (while I agree what you are saying is correct and answers the first question).